# Git with a CMS: when I uninstall plugins how do I reflect that in Git easily?

Tags: git, content-management-system

I'm working on a CMS - Joomla! and I am doing so collaboratively.  We make amendments to the code on separate branches and push and then deploy via Circle CI using FTP.

If I uninstall something on the live site, it removes some files and database entries.  We aren't currently storing the DB in Git just the files.

Although sometimes I can predict which files are removed, I can't always know them all.

The best way I can think to overcome this issue is to create a new branch, check out the new branch, delete all the files, then download all files/folders via FTP.

Then merge/push the branch.

That doesn't seem like necessarily the smoothest process, it almost seems as if the FTP should push to Git directly.  Does that make sense?  Can anyone suggest a better methodology?